# retrieving selected value from checkboxlist and using in sql query

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create a sql query based on the selected Item from checkboxlist. Just want to remove last comma from the code below.

```
    String queryt=" And Brand IN(";
        foreach (ListItem lst in brandcklist.Items)
        {
            if (lst.Selected == true)
            {
               queryt += "'"+lst.Text+"',";
            }
        }
        queryt += ")";
        Label3.Text = queryt;
```

output for this is 
**And Brand IN('BlackBerry','Karbonn',)**  
note the comma after karbonn, I don't want to add comma after last item.

Comment: You can use string.join. But you should worry about SQL injection

Comment: @Uriil can u explain. Currently i just need to do it for my exam tommorow so its ok i will manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this line

```
queryt += ")";
```

with

```
queryt=queryt.TrimEnd(',') +")";
```

Comment: Its not write. Output now is And Brand IN('BlackBerry','Micromax',

Comment: I tested it. It works fine. Did u replace the line - > queryt += ")"; ?

Comment: Yes its working. Actually intellicence selected another var query rather than queryt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
String queryt = string.Format(" And Brand IN ({0})", string.join(", ", brandcklist.Items.Where(p=>p.Selected).Select(p=>p.Text)))
```

But as i said, it' open for SQL injection. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause) is better description, how you should do this